# Error and Warning in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In `visual studio 2010` when i build a project all the error and warning come into Output Window of VS.But there is no way to differentiate the error and warning.Which is very irritating.Is there a way to show only Error no warning or a way so that error and warning can be easily differentiate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the **Error List**, on the **View** menu choose **Error List**.